# Scrapy shell can't find tags

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape one of the biggest e-commerce web sites of Turkey. I first normally wrote the necessary xpaths by using shell. Running the crawler, I realized that even though the links are crawled, most of the pages didn't have their items scraped.

In order to paraphrase my xpaths, I reopened the page in scrapy shell. **I realized that scrapy shell was unable to find most of the tags such as tr and td.[image]**

One of the pages of the search inquiry in the web site that I'm trying to scrape, having the failure with simple tags: [Link](https://www.sahibinden.com/kiralik-daire?pagingOffset=20&address_quarter=22780&address_quarter=22781&address_district=4892&address_district=2023&address_district=2034&address_district=2033&address_district=2032&address_district=2031&address_district=2030&address_district=999051&address_district=2037&address_district=2026&address_district=999096&address_district=2036&address_district=2024&address_district=2035&address_district=4624&address_district=999029&address_town=427&address_city=34)

How can this be possible? Is this a measure taken by the web site to prevent scraping? If so, any recommendations to bypass this?

Thanks in advance.

Because the web site isn't accessable from outside Turkey I'm adding the html code to this link: [HTML code](https://justpaste.it/8ltoc)

Comment: provide a download of the [link](https://www.sahibinden.com/kiralik-daire?pagingOffset=20&address_quarter=22780&address_quarter=22781&address_district=4892&address_district=2023&address_district=2034&address_district=2033&address_district=2032&address_district=2031&address_district=2030&address_district=999051&address_district=2037&address_district=2026&address_district=999096&address_district=2036&address_district=2024&address_district=2035&address_district=4624&address_district=999029&address_town=427&address_city=34) above as html since we can't access the page from outside Turkey

Comment: I added the html of the page to the link because it doesn't fit in directly as text

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to scrape from the page?

Comment: Price, title and rooms (values like 2+1)

Comment: I just checked response.body. There are values in response.body which are not the same as what's seen from inspect tool of the browser.

Comment: For example the tag containing the link to each post in the page is seen as following in inspect tool: 
<a class="classifiedTitle" title="ŞİŞLİ NİŞANTAŞIN,DA ASOS'TAN KİRALIK 3+1 KOMBİLİ KLİMALI DAİRE" href="/ilan/emlak-konut-kiralik-sisli-nisantasin%2Cda-asos-tan-kiralik-3-plus1-kombili-klimali-daire-861110261/detay">
    ŞİŞLİ NİŞANTAŞIN,DA ASOS'TAN KİRALIK 3+1 KOMBİLİ KLİMALI DAİRE</a>

Comment: But the response.body from the shell is following: 
<a s-click href="/ilan/emlak-konut-kiralik-sisli-osmanbey-nisantasi-efe-sokak-2-plus1-85-m2-2-kat-temiz-995773398/detay" class="search-classified-link mui-btn" >

Very weird